# Pass a returned value from a thread to another thread

Tags: multithreading, pointers

I'm learning posix thread programming and I'm struggling in the following program. So I've 2 threads with the ids: tid1 and tid2. I use the thread with tid1 to enter the values I want to sum each other into the second thread with tid2 but the result of the sum is not correct. So I've tried to display in tid2 the values I entered in tid1 but I realized that these are not correct too (didn't correspond to the entered values). Can you pleas tell me where I'm doing the error? The way I pass the pointer returned from a thread with tid1 to thread with tid2, is that correct?

Note: The values returned from tid1 are already correct because I checked it as you can also see in the main (line 56).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *entryValues(void *p)
{
   int nbVal = *(int*)p;
   int i = 0;
   int val = 0;
   int *tab;

   while(i < nbVal){
      printf("value %d: ", i);
      scanf("%d", &val);
      tab[i] = val;
      i++;
   }

   pthread_exit(tab);

}

void *sumValues(void *p)
{
    int *values;
    int sum = 0, i = 0;
    memcpy(values, (int*)p, sizeof((int*)p));
    printf("%d\n", values[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(values); i++)
    {
    //printf("value %d: %d\n", i, values[i]);
    sum += values[i];
    }
    printf("The sum of the entered values is: %d\n", sum);
    return NULL;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   pthread_t tid1;
   pthread_t tid2;
   int nbValues = 0;
   int *arr;

   printf("Please enter the number of values you want to sum each other: ");
   scanf("%d", &nbValues);
   if(pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, entryValues, &nbValues)!= 0)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "creation of thread failed\n");
    return -1;
   }

   pthread_join(tid1, (void**)&arr);
   //printf("array: %d\n", arr[0]);

   if(pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, sumValues, arr) != 0)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "creation of thread failed\n");
    return -1;
   }
   pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
   /* Waiting for the termination of tid */
   printf("End of main thread\n");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```